# Laravel Pagination with a Raw Query

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm using a raw SQL query in Laravel, because it was easier to me at the beginning to make complex queries, so I used them like that.

Now I want to get a list of comments of an user 7, and I would like to paginate the comments, in 5.

That's what I have:

```
$comments = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT users.name,  reviews.comment, reviews.comment_score FROM reviews JOIN users WHERE reviews.user_id = :logged_user;")
   ,array('logged_user' => $user_id,));
```

So this query depends on the user which is consulting the view, receives a variable.

All I see for pagination is with Eloquent queries, and I don't find any clear usage for this.

If I add '->paginate(5)' at the end of the last parenthesis, or later to the variable like $comments->paginate(5);  I get a:

Error: Call to a member function paginate() on array

Some light on this??

Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score -1):

You do something like this for pagination.

```
$perPage = $request->input("per_page", 10);
$page = $request->input("page", 1);
$skip = $page * $perPage;
 if($take < 1) { $take = 1; }
if($skip < 0) { $skip = 0; }

$comments = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT users.name,  reviews.comment, reviews.comment_score FROM reviews JOIN users WHERE reviews.user_id = :logged_user;"),array('logged_user' => $user_id,));

$totalCount = $comments->count();
$results = $comments
    ->take($perPage)
    ->skip($skip)
    ->get();
$paginator = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator($results, $totalCount, $take, $page);

return $paginator;
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't ever have come up with such a trick. =)

I have problems because I don't have any $request variable.

I just want to show a Welcome page, with sumarised information of one user page.

So I get:   Undefined variable: request

Thank you!

Comment: if you want to paginate your comment for one user , need some twigging in above code or you can use datatable for specific users comment pagination,

Comment: I know, but I dont know how to get $perPage and $page variables. I don't have any $request variable.

How could I get these two variables initialised?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: do one thing get simple user data as it is, and use datatable for comments, from https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables, i have used it in one of my project, you need to make new .function which will use in ajax for datatables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, really. Firstly I will try to convert it into Eloquent model. If I find it difficult, will check this solution!

Comment: $take is undefined